# In shiny, selecting unique values from a column in a reactive object to use as input choices

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make a shiny dashboard app in which the choices available in the dropdown menu are retrieved from a column in a reactive data object.

At the moment my code looks something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

data <- reactiveFileReader(
  intervalMillis = 100000,  
  NULL,
  filePath = 'Data\\data.csv',
  readFunc = read.csv,
  fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM"
)

header <- dashboardHeader(title = "test")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("plots", tabName = "plots"),
    pickerInput('to','To:',
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE, size = 10), multiple = TRUE,
                choices = NULL)
    )
  )

fluid1 <- fluidRow(
  box()
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = 'plots', h2(fluid1)
    )
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'test', header, sidebar, body, skin='blue')

server <- function(input, output){

  choices <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      select(to) %>%
      unique()
      })

  observe({updatePickerInput('to',choices = choices())})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And some sample data:

```
data <- data.frame(from = c('RCD', 'RCD', 'RCR', 'RCD', 'RCS', 'RCR', 'RCR', 'RCS', 'RCO', 'RCS'), 
                   to = c('RCS', 'RCR', 'RCO', 'RCO', 'RCR', 'RCD', 'RCS', 'RCD', 'RCR', 'RCO'),
                   n = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

What I expected was for this -

```
choices <- reactive({
    data() %>%
      select(to) %>%
      unique()
      })
```

to give me a list of unique values in the `to` column of the `data()` reactive object, which I could then pass to  `observe({updatePickerInput('to',choices = choices())})`

Instead I get this error:

```
Warning: Error in : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I'm quite new to using shiny so am having real problems troubleshooting this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Try adding `session` in your `updatePickerInput` statement (`updatePickerInput(session, 'to', choices = choices())`), and make sure `session` is in your server function: `server <- function(session, input, output)`

Comment: @Ben Amazing, thanks

Comment: @Ben post as an answer for some magic internet points

Comment: @hedgedandlevered Sure thing - happy to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes up often. You may have a working `shiny` app with a `server` method lacking a `session` parameter. But once you use methods like `updatePickerInput`, `updateSelectInput`, `updateTextInput`, etc. you run into an error, because it will require that you pass `session` to it. Thus, you need to make sure you include the `session` argument to your `server` function:

```
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  ...
}
```

The `session` object can be helpful in a number of circumstances, such as doing something when the browser is closed, customizing a user interface, updating inputs, or sending messages to javascript. For more information, see this [practical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58997674/3460670).

In the case of `updatePickerInput`, you are actually sending a message to a picker input on the session's client web page. If the input is present, then the binding object's `receiveMessage` method is called. The `updatePickerInput` is a friendly wrapper to use instead of the generic `sendInputMessage`. In this instance, try including `session`:

```
updatePickerInput(session, 'to', choices = choices())
```

A helpful reference on the `session` object:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html